Sketchbook pro ruler won't draw complete lines, what option do I need to toggle to fix this?
For some odd reason the ruler in sketchbook pro is not working as intended.  Despite me simply trying to draw a straight line it is randomly making it into a stripped line with randomw white spaces.  I'm using the pen tool with the ruler and the  vertical symmetry tool, using a wacom tablet.  I also had trouble with the square tool, earlier it randomly made on half of  the square not appear.  After I did a second square it created that one fine.

